# GMSProjection thread safety

Tags: google-maps-sdk-ios

Are GMSProjection and GMSMarkerOptions safe for use on background threads (assuming access is synchronized) ?

GMSMapView.h says specifically that GMSMapView and "related objects such as markers and polylines" are not thread safe, but does that also apply to a GMSProjection, which SEEMS like it might/should be safe given that it's an immutable object?

I ask because I want to do some fairly heavy location calculations on a worker thread, and I need a projection to do so.  Naturally, I would acquire the projection from the map and make any changes that result from the background work on the main thread.